# Microsoft Graph does not retrieve the Group's Plan Id

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

After creating a Group using `POST /v1.0/groups` with the body:

```
{
    "description": "hello",
    "displayName": "group_for_restore",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "group_for_restore",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": "Public"
}
```

A request to  `GET /v1.0/groups/{group-id}/planner/plans` does not retrieve any plans.

As far as I know, after creating a Group, a Plan will be created too. On the web interface you can see that this plan is correctly created and shown, but it does not appear in JSON response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.plannerPlan)",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```

After clicking on it in the web interface you can easily get the plan using the request above.

Is it ok to do such magic steps to fetch plan id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web App is provisioning the Group's Plan the first time you attempt to access it. When creating a Group through the API however, you'll need to create a new Plan yourself:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans
Content-type: application/json

{
  "owner": "group-id",
  "title": "title-value"
}
```

Keep in mind this important note from the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/planner_overview):

> When creating a new plan, make a group its owner by simply setting the `owner` property on a plan object.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work when creating groups via Flow with Application Permissions. Groups creation is allowed using Application Permissions, plan creation is not supported.