# Duplicate plans in Microsoft Planner

Tags: json, office365, microsoft-graph-api

The request to

> POST v1.0/groups

with the body:

```
{
    "description": "hello",
    "displayName": "group_for_restore",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "group_for_restore",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": "Public"
}
```

returns the **id** of the created group. After it I am using the request (create a plan) to

> POST v1.0/planner/plans

with the body:

```
{
  "owner": "{group-id}", // from the request above
  "title": "group_for_restore" // group name
}
```

When I go to the web interface office365 (planner) I see two plans with identical names. One of them is unreachable. 
Is it normal behavior? Or what should I do to see only one plan with the same name as group (or something like to create a group without default plan)?

Comment: We created a premier support call for this issue. Today we got confirmatiin that it was indeed a bug introduced a while ago. It is now fixed again.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced the same problem and would like to share my experience in the hopes that it helps fixing the underlying issue. Unfortunately I do not yet have enough reputation to include this as a reply to the previous comment.

When you go to your group's Planner for the first time via UI, the group's default plan gets provisioned with createdBy.application.id value of "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa", which points to the Planner app. However, if you instead provision a plan programmatically with your own app, the createdBy.application.id value is the GUID of your app. The createdBy.application.id value is also different, if you add a new plan to a Teams channel (points to Teams app).

In Planner, there are tiles under "All plans" for every group, which direct the user to the default plan of the group (and provision it, if it has not yet been provisioned). When you programmatically create your plan, a new tile is created for it, and the original tile stops working and shows an error when you click on it. The same thing happens, if you navigate to the group in Outlook and click the Planner link there.

It would seem that these Planner links use the createdBy.application.id value to distinguish which plan is the default plan of the group. They expect to find a plan with createdBy.application.id value of "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa", and when there's a plan with some random GUID instead, an unexpected error occurs. So, what we would need to be able to do, is to programmatically provision a plan with createdBy.application.id value of "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa", but alas, that property is read only and hence can't be defined in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't expected. Based on your description, you are doing everything correctly, and should end up with one entry in the UI. We'll investigate the issue. If you have it, request id for the plan creation would help us identify the problem.

Comment: What request id should I provide you with?

Comment: If you mean the request id that I get in the response after creation plan, ok I will give it to you, but it always changing. As for the plan, after creation a group in the web interface appears a plan with the name of the group, but I cannot get it`s id! I can do it only after clicking on it. My colleague has already asked about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494611/microsoft-graph-does-not-retrieve-the-groups-plan-id . So the problem still exists.

Comment: Any one of the request ids for plan creations would work. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the request-id: c8be37fb-706f-4cb8-8243-a592b4398497